# Updating images referenced in style sheet and caching

Tags: html, css, caching

Would my image update if is referenced from css and is cached on users device?

I have old website and I want to make sure all users gets new image.

I have updated my css link to use additional query string, that will force update of the style sheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/site.css" />
```

Which will make sure that my styles will update once user accesses the page.
The question is  about referenced images

```
.header {
    background-image: url(../logo.gif);
}
```

Issue is I need to keep my image the same, as it is referenced throughout the page and another pages.

Do I need to put query string inside of the css image link too as follows

```
  .header {
        background-image: url(../logo.gif?v=1);
    }
```

My understanding is that I need to use solution two,
the image because it will be resolved as http://www.example.com/logo.gif and therefore it will be checked against browser ie: I need to add the querystring into css.

Answer (score 0):

> In modern web browsers it should work. Browser will check address of
>   image and there is change (**?v=whatever**) - this url
>   **img.jpg?v=whatever** is not cached so browser will load it again.